# Add properties to artifacts while uploading to Artifactory

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, properties-file

I have a directory tree like below and I need to upload the complete structure as it is to Artifactory using Jenkins. Now I could not find a way to assign properties to all files under 'Delhi' to have `Continent(property name)=Asia, CountryName=India` and similarly for Nepal and so for 'Australia'.
![Asia
--India
  ---Delhi
      state.txt
      abc.ste
--Nepal
    Kathmandu.txt
Australia
--NSW
  ---Sydney
      abc.tst
      cbd.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0avM.jpg)

I have tried Jenkins Artifactory plugin where I have option to use deployment properties but no way to do such conditional property assignment, instead it applies to the whole directory tree mentioned in 'Published Artifacts". Also I have tried EnvInject which too injects property and applies to all.

Answer (score 13):

I'm assuming that you'd like to use the "Generic-Artifactory Integration" to deploy your artifacts.
One way to achieve what you're looking for is to use the Generic Artifactory Integration together with the MultiJob Plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin
having your Artifactory deployment split into different jobs each with different deployment properties, which values can be controlled from the main job.
Another possible solution is to have your Jenkins job deploy the whole tree without properties, and then use the "Set Item Properties" Artifactory REST API on each folder:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-SetItemProperties
When a folder is used with this API, property attachment is recursive by default.